# Emulating guitar pickup loading effects with a floating gyrator?

Tags: audio, analog, guitar-pedal

I'm looking to construct a high impedance buffer which emulates the loading effects of an electric guitar connected to a nonlinear, low input impedance amplifier such as the Dallas Rangemaster (pictured below).

[image: Dallas Rangemaster Schematic]

While it's easy to model the frequency response of an RLC circuit in a vacuum, it's also interacting with the nonlinearity of Q1 (both the diode V-I curve and the miller effect in a nonlinear amplifier seem significant here).

[image: L: induced R: driven]

One way would be to externally drive a real pickup with a voltage source and connect the other terminal to the Q1 input.  This is a) expensive, b) noise-prone, and c) changes the topology of the quite significant parasitic capacitance of the pickup from series to parallel (as compared to what's seen by an induced voltage in the coils).  Therefore it seems like an undesirable approach.

A more desirable solution would be to build a floating (gyrator) inductor.  While it's easy to find information on grounded gyrators, information on floating gyrators seems more sparse.

Therefore I am wondering

1. Is the floating gyrator approach reasonable, or am I likely to get poor results in practice?
2. For my application (audio frequency, ESR must be well-specified but it doesn't need to go below a few kOhms) is there a recommended floating gyrator topology that will have good results?

Comment: *I'm looking to construct*? Do you mean construct or simulate? Are you trying to simulate a geetar pup?

Comment: I'm trying to emulate it in hardware.

Comment: Why not just use a guitar pick up then?

Comment: Practical considerations aside, by my understanding this is a different circuit (see image for comparison).

Comment: Truthfully I don’t understand what this question is or what you are trying to achieve.